# How to auto populate other field based on the selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I have created this page to fetch data from my database based on the selection of drop down which is also derived from the database. Please help me in this regard as I am stuck with no luck. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rajat123", "callboard");
$data = "select * from customermaster";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $data);
?>
<form name="sysadd" id="form1" method="post" action="system_reg2.php">
Customer Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="custname" id="custname" onchange="updatetext()">
<?php
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$row['custname']}\">";
        echo $row['custname'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
?>
</select><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" />
<input type="text" name="sl_no" id="sl_no" />
<input type="text" name="config" id="service" />
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function updateText() {
            var custname2 = document.getElementById("custname").value;
            <?php $data2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM customermaster WHERE custname = 'custname2'") ; ?> 
            <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data2); ?>
          document.getElementById("type").value = <?php echo $row['type'] ?>;
          document.form1.sl_no.value = <?php echo $row['sl_no'] ?>;
          document.form1.config.value = <?php echo $row['config'] ?>;
          document.form1.date.value = <?php echo $row['date'] ?>;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide more information including what is actually happening, what is the problem, what is the exact expected behavior. Without comprehensive information it is a poor question, not very useful to the public and has the capability to be downvoted and maybe closed.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing server-side scripting with client-side scripting.  PHP and mySQL are both server-side scripting. You can't use javascript (client-side scripting) to update server-side data on the page after the page has loaded.  You will have to have the page submit after the user changes the first drop-down and have PHP read what the user entered and display the next item.  I would leave the form action blank so the form submits to its own page, so all the code is in one page.

Example form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Example PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['form_variable']))
{
    // Perform lookup of next drop-down data based on last drop-down data
}
```

After all the drop-downs are populated you can use PHP to redirect to `system_reg2.php`, or just have a submit button at the bottom of the page that does it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP generates a HTML page sent to client. When accomplished, the request is closed and it is on the user agent (the browser) to handle everything else. You either have to provide all the possible data in the request before or you have to send the choice back to the server to request a new response with data based on your current selection. You can do it by reloading the hole page or you update a part of your page by javascript requesting the needed date via AJAX. JQuery is a framework aiding to handle AJAX requests easier.